# need to phonenumber from table abc in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

```
{
  "id": "1234",
  "applicant": [
    {
      "phone": [
        {
          "prirotynumber": "1",
          "areacode": "407",
          "linenumber": "1234",
          "exchangenumber": "7899"
        },
        {
          "prirotynumber": "27",
          "areacode": "407",
          "linenumber": "1234",
          "exchangenumber": "79999"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

for this id=1234 i need to fetch  homephonenuber  as applicant.phone.areacode+applicant.phone+linenumber+ applicant.phone+exchangenumber if prirotynumber=1
and
cellphone as applicant.phone.areacode+applicant.phone+linenumber+ applicant.phone+exchangenumber if prirotynumber=27

Expected result here:

```
{
    "key":"value"
}
```

Comment: i my find phonenumber for this id

Comment: can we get cellphone and home phone with unwind applicant.phone

Comment: don't give expected result in comment. Edit your own question.

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't what you need, make your expected result more clarify with right sample data.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "id": "1234",
      "applicant.phone.prirotynumber": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$applicant"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$applicant.phone"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "applicant.phone.prirotynumber": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "homePhoneNumber ": {
        $concat: [
          "$applicant.phone.areacode",
          "-",
          "$applicant.phone.linenumber",
          "-",
          "$applicant.phone.exchangenumber"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D6Rq0019lZP)